# Azure Devops Build Cancel with multiple Agents

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am using Azure devops as a service. I have a build with multiple agents. This is partly to organize the build tasks into logical groups and also because one the Agents is used with a Multi-Configuration/Multiplier to perform a set of tasks n times. Each agent has a dependency on the one before it.

It appears the pipeline queues all the agents. The problem is when I cancel a build, the current agent may be canceled -- but the next agent queued continues.

For example, the Multiplier agent queues n instances. Canceling the build only cancels the current agent - the next one in the queue then starts up.

How do I get the build to cancel in it's entirety when you "Cancel" the build ?

Comment: Select the agent in your build-definition, go to "Additional options" and make sure you set 'Run this job' to 'Only when all previous jobs have succeeded'. Also it isn't a bad idea to set the "Job cancel timeout" to "0" on the agent and "1" in the buildoptions

Comment: Do you have 1 build pipeline with multiple agent jobs?